# How to count occurrences of special type of character in string in php

Tags: php

I have a string

```
Hobbies#14285723739878005#reading#Reading
```

I need the count of number of occurrence of '#' in the string. How to get that?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: oops sorry i confused betn timing...

Comment: if you guys thing my code is just a copy of other code i was delete my post and all the repo i earn with this question get back to stack-overflow ..cheers!!

Comment: hey..dont get angry. you both gave right ans. I got confused between the timing of both. i understand that first one finished typing when the second one was typing......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
<?php
echo substr_count("Hobbies#14285723739878005#reading#Reading","#");
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
3
```

For your reference [Click Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ja7s4k)

Answer (score 0):

substr_count() should do what you need:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr_count.asp